# Connect Raspberry PI to internet through network bridge

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, raspberry-pi

I want to connect Raspberry PI to internet over network bridge on my laptop. It's Windows 8.1 machine. I've bridged ethernet and wireless interfaces. Raspberry PI has a static IP address. I was trying as the following [tutorial](http://joshwoodcomputing.blogspot.com/2012/08/creating-network-bridge-from-winows-7.html) says.

Router `192.168.1.1`

Windows `192.168.1.15`

Raspberry PI `192.168.1.100`

I can ping router and Raspberry from PC, also PC from Raspberry. The problem is when i try to ping Router or google.pl from Raspberry:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7006ms
```

The firewall on PC is turned off. Here is `ifconfig`:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:9a:ea:1d
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:426 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:133358 (130.2 KiB)  TX bytes:54438 (53.1 KiB)
```

Routing table:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

ARP table:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.1              ether   88:ae:1d:7e:07:2f   C                     eth0
192.168.1.15             ether   88:ae:1d:7e:07:2f   C                     eth0
```

and interfaces

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

I've tried manipulating with interfaces, default gateway, nothing seems working.

`ipconfig -all` from windows is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9h24j3tn1otlhl/ipconfig.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Ipconfig /all from Windows, please?

Comment: Luke, thank you for answer, the ipconfig -all is here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9h24j3tn1otlhl/ipconfig.txt?dl=0)